# Adding background color to text-layout cells

Tags: 2013, page-layout, design

Im looking for a way to modtify just ONE of the costume text-layout cells, namely the 'header' one. I'm currently using the one that has two colums along with a header and a footer.

I've messed around with the inspect tool in IE, and can see that each of the four cells are defined by the same #class(The class is called ms-rte-layoutszone-inner). This means means I can't just a simple css snippet changing the background of said cell.

So my question is, is there a way to add a background color to only the first cell without affecting the other ones?

Any help is greatly appriciated!

```
<table id="XY">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer">
    <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner">  // Background only on this one
     <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer">
    <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner">
     <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer">
    <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner">
     <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer">
    <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner">
     <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selector 'first-child'.
For example:

```
table tr:first-child .ms-rte-layoutszone-inner {
    background: yellow;
}
```

By this way only first element with class ms-rte-layoutszone-inner will have yellow background.

Comment: If this will not help, attach please snippet with your html structure where all 4 headers displayed.

Also you can write simple javascript code. If you have reference to jQuery on the page, code will be - 
`$('.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner').first().css("background-color", "yellow");`

Comment: Won't this target the first element within all the instances of '.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner'? Ideally what I want is to only affect the first div that uses .ms-rte-layoutszone.

Unfortunately I work on a restricted system so I can't print the exact code, but i wrote down something that has basically the same setup.

Comment: @KimA i edited code in my answer.
This code will work for your snippet

`<style>
table tr:first-child .ms-rte-layoutszone-inner {
    background: red;
}
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to creating a custom page layout where you wrap the required sections in your class

Comment: Is there a way to do this without sharepoint designer?

Comment: We usually makes new ones in code, as SPD is the very last option for us